# How to properly free an allocated memory in C?

Tags: c, malloc, free

I have two functions. In `find_host(...)` I allocated memory which I want to `free` in `main` function.

```
char* find_host(char* filename){
    char *x = malloc(20);
    sprintf(x, filename);
    const char* t = "10";
    int len = (int) strcspn(filename, t);
    x[len] = '\0';
    return ++x;
}

int main(){
    char *filename = "/CERN0/out_79.MERGE";
    char *word = find_host(filename);
    free(word);
    return 0;
}
```

But `free(word)` gives me:

```
*** Error in `/home/ken/.CLion2016.2/system/cmake/generated/First-6a656bbe/6a656bbe/Debug/First': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00000000008b1011 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x77725)[0x7f926862f725]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7ff4a)[0x7f9268637f4a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7f926863babc]
/home/ken/.CLion2016.2/system/cmake/generated/First-6a656bbe/6a656bbe/Debug/First[0x4006e9]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f92685d8830]
/home/ken/.CLion2016.2/system/cmake/generated/First-6a656bbe/6a656bbe/Debug/First[0x400579]
======= Memory map: ========
```

How should correctly `free` memory?

Comment: You are not returning - and freeing - the pointer given by `malloc`. You have altered it. You can only `free` the exact value that you were given.

Comment: Why `return ++x`?

Comment: Because I want to return `"CERN"`, not `"/CERN"`.

Comment: Then `return x;` and use `find_host(filename) + 1;`

Comment: The whole exercise seems futile. Why not just `printf("%s\n", filename+1);` ? Or otherwise use `filename+1` to skip the first character instead of this rigmarole.

Comment: @WeatherVane what about cutting back end of `"/CERN0/out_79.MERGE"` to make `"CERN"`?

Comment: You can also create another pointer and assign it to the original malloc'd pointer and then increment that one. Just make sure you call ```free``` on the original.

Comment: @RomaKarageorgievich then please ask that as a new question. This one is about freeing a pointer.

Comment: `char *x = malloc(20);` is weak in the size anyway. You should be using the length + 1 of the string passed.

Comment: `sprintf(x, filename);` is scary code.  What if the passed-in filename had a `%` in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only call `free()` on the pointer value actually returned by a call to `malloc()` and its brethren. Since you wish to skip the initial character, you can do the skipping when you populate the buffer rather than return an altered pointer.

```
char* find_host(char* filename){
    size_t sz = strlen(filename);
    char *x = malloc(sz);
    snprintf(x, sz, "%s", filename + 1);
    const char* t = "10";
    int len = (int) strcspn(filename, t);
    x[len] = '\0';
    return x;
}
```

Comment: It still gives me an error. Maybe in case of `x[len] = '\0'`?

Comment: @RomaKarageorgievich You're welcome. I replaced `sprintf` with `strcpy`

Comment: @jxh Funny thing with `No error:` :)) moreover when `stdlib.h` and `string.h` are missing. Ideone is not the best choice Anyway.

Comment: ....you do know that this `snprintf(x, sz, filename + 1);` means this `error: format not a string literal and no format arguments`?

Comment: @jxh I know, it is just a Warning. One should probably use `strcpy` there.